# Question about using auto for type inference of member function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

My question is about member function pointer. Here a sample code:
class `C` inherits `foo` from `A` and `bar` from `B`.
I expected both `&C::foo` and `&C::bar` are of the same type `void (C::*)()`,
but actually they are different types, one is `void(A::*)()`
and the other is `void(B::*)()`. I used gdb ptype command to inspected
data types.

My question is: is this behavior defined by C++ standards? What is the rationale of this design decision?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  void foo() {
    std::cout << this << std::endl;
  }
  int a;
};

struct B {
  void bar() {
    std::cout << this << std::endl;
  }
  int b;
};

struct C : public A, B { };

int main() {
  auto p1 = &C::foo;  // p1 is void (A::*)();
  auto p2 = &C::bar;  // p2 is void (B::*)();

  auto p3 = &A::foo;  // p3 is void (A::*)();

  bool b1 = std::is_same<decltype(p1), decltype(p2)>::value;
  bool b2 = std::is_same<decltype(p1), decltype(p3)>::value;
  std::cout << b1 << std::endl; // false
  std::cout << b2 << std::endl; // true
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*is this behavior defined by C++ standards?*" If it wasn't, then it would be a compiler bug. Is there some reason to suspect that it is a compiler bug? That is, why do you think that `C` has a `foo` or a `bar`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is specified by the standard:

When you have a class that inherits from other classes, the members of those classes ***are not*** members of the derived class. They are still members of their classes, and the derived class ***inherits*** them. So, the members of `A` and `B` are still members of `A` and `B`, and that's still reflected in their type, where appropriate. This is pretty much a core principle of C++, and you are simply observing this in action.

Just like when you put a bunch of books on your bookshelf, the chapters in those books do not become a part of the bookshelf. They are still the same chapters in the book, and your bookshelf is the means to access them.

Similarly, you can use `C` to access members of its parent classes, `A` and `B`, using the name of the class `C`. But they are still members of `A` and `B`, and it's reflected in their type.

When use use `auto`, you get the exact type of your expression. C++ allows you to convert a pointer to a member of a base class into a pointer to a member of a derived class. However, this is a ***conversion***. A conversion does not happen when using `auto` because that's exactly what `auto` is for: use whatever the actual type of the expression is, to initialize/construct the object, and don't do any conversions (there are some fine details here that add a few twists here, with respect to references, but it's not germane to this discussion).

Comment: @Sam It's a nice explanation. Thanks. But bookshelf, book example feels more like a composition than inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

The rationale behind this choice is the fact that the less you are assuming about a type, the better it is.

`C` is a `A`, so `(A::foo*)()` is the most generic type for the member function inherited from A.

Why would you want to enforce a stricter type? It's a win-win situation.